# Convert UIView center coordinates from local to window base coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the center points of all UITabBar subviews in the window base coordinate system using the following code.

```
func getHighlightLocations() -> [CGPoint] {
    var cgpointArray = [CGPoint]()

    self.tabBar.subviews.foreach {
            let point =  $0.convert($0.center, to: nil)
            cgpointArray.append(point)
    }
    return cgpointArray
}
```

The issue i have is the coordinates returned fall outside the device screen

```
po cgpointArray
▿ <Array<CGPoint>>
  ▿ some : 6 elements
    ▿ 0 : (252.0, 123.3)
      - x : 252.0
      - y : 123.3
    ▿ 1 : (207.0, 844.0)
      - x : 207.0
      - y : 844.0
    ▿ 2 : (54.0, 828.5)
      - x : 54.0
      - y : 828.5
    ▿ 3 : (261.5, 828.5)
      - x : 261.5
      - y : 828.5
    ▿ 4 : (675.5, 828.5)
      - x : 675.5
      - y : 828.5
    ▿ 5 : (468.0, 828.5)
      - x : 468.0
      - y : 828.5
```

What could I be doing wrong ?, Why don't return points fall within window device screen.

Comment: What iOS device (simulated or real) is this running on?

Comment: Simulated device iphone XR

Comment: The iPhone XR screen height is 896pt, so your points are on screen.

Comment: The points in the x axis are not on the screen for 4 and 5

Comment: Is it possible the method is being called before the views have been laid out? Also, the view hierarchy isn't documented anywhere (ie. private) so there are no guarantees how it is laid out.

Comment: Calling the above code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` yields the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to convert *from the tabbar view* ... so, try it like this:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    func getHighlightLocations() -> [CGPoint] {
        var cgpointArray = [CGPoint]()

        tabBar.subviews.forEach {
            let point = tabBar.convert($0.center, to: nil)
            cgpointArray.append(point)
        }

        return cgpointArray
    }

}
```

For a 3-item tab bar, I get this as a result (the first point is from the tabbar's background view):

```
[(187.5, 642.5), (62.5, 643.0), (187.5, 643.0), (312.5, 643.0)]
```

Comment: Yes this, works. Thanks. What is the reason behind using the tabBar as a conversion view.

Comment: Without a source view / coordinate space, how is `convert()` supposed to know what to do? All you are giving it is a `CGPoint` without any context.

Comment: Another way to look at this is to consider that a view's `center` point is relative to its parent view, not itself. Technically the code should be `$0.superview!.convert($0.center, to: nil)`. But since, in this case, we know the superview is `tabBar`, using `tabBar.convert...` works too.